# Javascript change inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml

I'd like to change the value of a label depending on the status of its checkbox

```js
function private() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("private");// Get the checkbox
  var text = document.querySelector('label[for="private"]');// Get the output text

  if (checkBox.checked == true)
  {
    text.innerHTML = "Public";
  } else {
    text.innerHTML = "Private";
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input id="private" type="checkbox" onclick="private()" />
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
<label for="private"></label>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: @HereticMonkey it helps but it doesn't work anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a nodelist, so you need to specify the element you want like:

```js
function private() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("private");// Get the checkbox
  var text = document.querySelectorAll('label[for="private"]')[0];// Get the output text

  if (checkBox.checked == true)
  {
    text.innerHTML = "Public";
  } else {
    text.innerHTML = "Private";
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input id="private" type="checkbox" onclick="private()" />
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
<label for="private"></label>
```

Or maybe just use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead which only returns the first match:

```js
function private() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("private");// Get the checkbox
  var text = document.querySelector('label[for="private"]');// Get the output text

  if (checkBox.checked == true)
  {
    text.innerHTML = "Public";
  } else {
    text.innerHTML = "Private";
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input id="private" type="checkbox" onclick="private()" />
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
<label for="private"></label>
```

Comment: I have done it but nothing changed... Have you modified anything else to make it work?

Comment: @Fox Nope, you can see the complete working code examples right in my answer. Have you checked your browser's console for errors? Is that code you posted in your question an accurate and complete representation of your issue?

Comment: console says: "private is not a function"

Comment: @Fox Sounds like a typo somewhere

Comment: of course... but I checked it and there's no typo! Can a function conflict with a *id* name?

Comment: @Fox Yes but as you can see from the answers and code examples that's not the case here. Are you using a framework of some kind?

Comment: no frameworks... I'm a complete beginner in JS so there shouldn't be strange settings which alter the result

Comment: @Fox Is the code you say isn't working much different from what you've posted?

Comment: Solved by changing the name of the function with something else... Maybe *private* is a forbidden keyword as used for class members' scope

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `querySelector()` not `querySelectorAll()`. By getting all elements, you would have to iterate through the list of items (even though there is only 1).

```js
function private() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("private");// Get the checkbox
  var text = document.querySelector('label[for="private"]');// Get the output text

  if (checkBox.checked == true)
  {
    text.innerHTML = "Public";
  } else {
    text.innerHTML = "Private";
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input id="private" type="checkbox" onclick="private()" />
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
<label for="private"></label>
```

Comment: Then you have some other issue going on. Check your console logs. You can clearly see in the code snippet here that it is functioning.

Comment: it says `Uncaught TypeError: private is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick`

Comment: @Fox that is unrelated to the question you posted which this correctly answers and it's a dupe to boot. If you have another question, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things that I would suggest that will solve your problem:

- Pass the `event` object to your function. This contains everything about the `click` event, *including* what element was clicked on. This means you don't have to scour the DOM.
- Do **not** wrap a form control with a **label**. This is not how labels were intended to work. Instead use something like a `section` tag.
- Form controls and their labels are automatically connected when a `for` attribute is provided. The other can be found through `control.labels[0]` or `label.htmlFor`. This is particularly why you want to adhere to the standard of **not wrapping controls with labels**

---

With these adjustments, and the addition of a *ternary* condition statement to determine what text to display, the code will look like this:

```
<section class="switch">
  <input id="private" type="checkbox" onclick="private(event)" />
  <span class="slider"></span>
</section>

<label for="private"></label>

function private(e) {
  var checkBox = e.currentTarget,
  label = checkBox.labels[0];

  label.textContent = checkBox.checked ? "Public" : "Private";
}
```

### Example:

```js
function private(e) {
  var checkBox = e.currentTarget,
  label = checkBox.labels[0];
  
  label.textContent = checkBox.checked ? "Public" : "Private";
}
```

```html
<section class="switch">
  <input id="private" type="checkbox" onclick="private(event)" />
  <span class="slider"></span>
</section>

<label for="private"></label>
```